# doesn't write shapefile in R

Tags: r

I joined 'csv' data to shapefile data by R. File join was successful, but I can't save shapefile. I used the following code

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
data1 <- rgdal::readOGR("Path")

data2 <- read.csv("Path")

dfdata <- data.frame(data1)

dfdata2 <- data.frame(data2)

df <- inner_join(dfdata, dfdata2, by = 'val')

df <- distinct(dfdata3, gid, rank)

dfdata3 <- mutate(dfdata2, gid)

df1 <- left_join(dfdata, dfdata3, by = 'gid')

data1@data <- df1

writeOGR(data1, "Path/vl_blk_.shp", 'data1', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

error message is

> Error in writeOGR(data1, "Path/vl_blk_.shp", "data1",  :
> Layer creation failed*

How do I save this file?

Comment: have you tried doing it without the driver argument?

Comment: I solved problem. Path was wrong. thanks to comment.